# My Raspberry Pi disconnects from the Wi-Fi network randomly

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless, settings

I am experiencing an issue related to wifi network sleeping or disconnecting, that has been persisting despite trying this methods:

- Changing the power management setting to off using iwconfig wlan0
  power off
- Editing the /etc/network/interfaces file to include:

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d wireless-power off

but these don't seem to work. When I connect my raspberry pi to my monitor and login, thats when the wifi connects again and everything is fine.

Is there a work-around to this - such as having a script run to reboot the server and so it can activate the network or something?

Also, I'm using a raspberry A+ model.

Comment: What Raspbian version do you use? Is it stretch? With stretch `/etc/network/interfaces` isn't used by default. Also power management isn't an issue anymore since years, no need to fiddle with it. It is disabled in the driver. What server you are talking about?

Comment: @Ingo I’m using noobs. I’m using a raspberry pi A+ model

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I thought it was my power supply because I was having under voltage problems. What I did was

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

file should start like this:

```
#interfaces(5) file used by if(8) and ifdown(8)
...
#Incule files form /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

I literally just added:

```
wireless-power off
```

And hit ctr+X, Y and ENTER
and make sure to reboot after

```
sudo reboot
```

and the problem should be fix